# Consolidating views / Adding criteria on-top of existing view

Tags: postgresql, view, filter, criteria

I Have a top level `view` stored in schema `schem1` that drives it's data from some table that masks out irrelevant data.
The application issues multiple different criterias on the data in order to mask out other rows for other reasons.

The data processing is done with stored procedures. I would like that the application would have an ability to issue whatever filter it wants (OR NOT) back to a TEMPORARY view in a way that the application could "add-up" filters as it wishes, In other words, I'm looking for a way to store a temporary view with that drives it's data from the preceding temporary view that the new view is taking it's place.

Alternative explanation to what I want to achieve is a way to combine new criteria on-top of existing view so that fallowing references to that view would use the 'base view+new criteria'

As far as I can tell, pgsql does not "*compile*" the view, but uses it as is SQL text, so referencing the same `view` is considered a recursive call (When in fact what I would like to do is reference the "previous layer view" in the FROM clause).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're actually looking for a temporary table, e.g.:

```
create temporary table current_data as
select * from filtered_view;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html

Follow it as needed by straightforward inserts if the extra rows aren't in there already, and anti-joins if not e.g.:

```
insert into current_data
select * from other_view
left join current_data using (whatever_pkey)
where current_data is null;
```

Once you're done filling the temporary table, run `analyze current_data` and create applicable indexes if it contains enough data, then proceed to use it in queries as you'd normally do.

Comment: No, temporary table will populate data, will cause unneeded memory overhead, might populate irrelevant data, and would cause performance downgrade I believe. Ad-hoc queries are best here as for the criteria fields would be indexed as needed.

Comment: Err, it won't have irrelevant data unless you populate it that way. At any rate, you cannot alter a view using that view's definition, as you've already found out. So I was pointing out the (imho) credible alternative.

Comment: Sure, but What good is it for if i need to populate it *after* the application knows the filter.
This alternative is quite obvious, sorry.

The best thing for me could have been if I can overwrite temporary view with another temporary view - just thought of another idea

Comment: In a word, performance. Your intent isn't very clear in the question, but if this view of yours is to create complicated reports, then you'll be better off with one or more temporary tables than you will with enormous — not to mention mutable — views. If, on the other hand, you're looking into this for day to day queries, then — no offense — your approach is likely incorrect. If the latter, define a view or ten as is needed for convenience, and apply where clauses on them as appropriate or use an ORM with a query builder to generate these where clauses for you.

Comment: It's not necessarily for report, I have a few queries that does a bunch of stuff. I want them to be able to work on a subset of the records however the application chooses. that is, kindda like letting the application change the stored procedure. The procedures are not so simple so managing/generating them in the ORM - i'm not sure if possible (and doesn't seem to me like best practice, I Favor SP any day)

Comment: Be wary of trying to do too much in queries, btw. More often than not it's better to retrieve a final set of rows, and then fetch related rows from dependencies with `in (…)` clauses, than it is to try to fetch everything in one go using giant joins with convoluted where group by clauses. Regarding the ORM, some of them are quite good nowadays, e.g. Sequel in Ruby have full fledged query builders that are extremely adequate when used with Postgres. Doctrine in PHP is good as well. Just stay away from the "traditional" ActiveRecord pattern: use an ORM with a proper AST (abstract syntax tree).

Answer (score 1):

Views in postgres are not the best tool for dynamic filtering data.
Creating new view each time you define a new filter is looking for trouble (not mention performance costs).

To generate reports in my applications I use functions returning queries. 
These functions have filter values as arguments.
You can consider them as *parametrized views*.

To fulfill your conditions I propose the following solution. 
Of course, it's only an outline.

Let's say **customers** is your top level view and it contains field **name**.

Create a table in which we'll store numbered filters:

```
create table filters (
    id serial primary key,
    filter text);
```

To define new filter you simply insert it into the table:

```
insert into filters (filter)
values ('name like ''%John%''');
```

And define our *parametrized view* as a function which generates data from **customers** filtered by values from table **filters**:

```
create or replace function show_customers()
    returns setof customers
    language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    _filter text;
    _query text = 'select * from customers where true ';
begin
    for _filter in 
        select filter from filters order by id
    loop
        _query = _query || ' and (' || _filter || ')';
    end loop;
    return query execute _query;
end $$;
```

Now if you call that function you'll obtain filtered data depending on current state of **filters** table.

```
select * from show_customers();
```

Note that you have a full control on current filters. You can reset them by emptying table filters, you can remove one or more and so on.

Comment: First, that's a cool idea, second, `parametrized view`? Please don't refer it as a view if execution across the entire table is needed even if LIMIT 1 (SP). ( What are the performance costs with views? views operate as if I were to add the criterias to the referenced tables in the SP. The Sp should be created with an orientation that they are views, though )
[ See other comment for further details: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206493/consolidating-views-adding-criteria-on-top-of-existing-view#comment35932915_23387219 ]

Comment: Glitches you may run into with approach relate to row estimates by the planner (it'll be 1k rows unless you tell it otherwise in the function's definition), and more importantly the use of indexes in the event of joins with set returning functions — you'll typically get a hash or a merge plan instead of a nested loop plan when the number of rows returned is appropriately small that the nested loop plan would in fact the better one.

Comment: As it is not quite clear in your question, I thought (probably wrong) about a situation where a user can unrestrainedly define new criteria in your application. In this case costs of creating generous amount of views would be huge. Views in postgres are not just a stored queries. In fact they are regular tables without data but with rules defined. In general I think your idea is unrealizable. First, you cannot create recursive view. Second, if you use nested views, the bottom one is always executed across the entire table.

Comment: Btw, I have just implemented the above solution in one of my applications. It runs like hell! ;) Thank you for the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

One option (If u have another idea please answer) is to pull out the query from the schema definition of the view, and assign it as a table for the new filter to pull FROM it.

i.e. if the view is

```
select * from users;
```

then we drop the old view and create a new one with the new criteria USING the existing view
the new view would then be composed out of a query like

```
select * FROM ( select * from users ) as t where user_id>100
```

In that way additional filters could be added on-top each other in a similar fashion.

Comment: Ya, that works unless you've any type of aggregates as such. If your example view is more like select id, sum(field) from users group by id, you can get naster performance issues.

Comment: My solution might not even work, the SP's are compiled, we might not have the ability to drop the view since the SP's are dependent.

Comment: Ya: if you drop the views, the SP will get dropped as well. The SP aren't "compiled", btw. Rather, their query plan is prepared and cached when they're called for the first time. (It's a bit smarter than that in reality, but that is the gist of what is going on.)